# autoload.php issue: failed to open stream: no such file or directory

Tags: php, php-amqp

I am new to PHP and trying to figure out issues with autoload.php. I downloaded php-amqplib package and it's dependencies and trying to test PHP page. I am getting failed to open stream: No such file or directory 'D:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\vendor\videlalvaro\php-amqplib\demo/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear'). I am using 5.3.13 and it's installed in 'D:\PHP5313' folder. There is no 'pear' folder. Could you please let me know if I am missing something? Thanks for any suggestions.

### autoload.php

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/composer' . '/autoload_real.php';

return ComposerAutoloaderInit5e74aaf68e13rfe5f321c5a586eb96f22::getLoader();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Php - Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/php-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path to the required file it not correct (autoload.php).

`__DIR__` is the actual directory where the file is located. I think you have to go back to come to the folder where the `autoload.php` is located.

```
D:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\vendor\videlalvaro\php-amqplib\demo/../vendor/autoload.php'
```

I think you have to go back to the vendor folder in your case where normally the autoload file is located. I think its 3 folders higher.

Comment: Autoload.php is located at D:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\vendor. Where do I have to make correction?

Comment: On the place where you include the autoload.php i think you use `__DIR__` then go back with `__DIR__."/../../"` until you are on the correct location.